# Get list of years when posts have been published

Tags: functions, archives, date

I want to create a list of posts from a Custom Post Type and add some filters the user can click to filter the list.

I added filters for all the categories by using the get_terms() function. Now I want to add filters by year, so I need a way to retrieve a list of all the years in which at least one post has been published...

I just need something like:

```
$years = get_all_years_with_posts();
// returns array( 2011, 2013, 2014 )
```

I know I can grab all the posts, check their year, and build the list myself, but is not there any other approach?

Answer (score 16):

Your question is pretty old, but I just wanted to add a real solution to your question. Here's a function that will return an array of years you have posts published in. You can put this function in functions.php or in a plugin or whatever you want.

```
function get_posts_years_array() {
    global $wpdb;
    $result = array();
    $years = $wpdb->get_results(
        $wpdb->prepare(
            "SELECT YEAR(post_date) FROM {$wpdb->posts} WHERE post_status = 'publish' GROUP BY YEAR(post_date) DESC"
        ),
        ARRAY_N
    );
    if ( is_array( $years ) && count( $years ) > 0 ) {
        foreach ( $years as $year ) {
            $result[] = $year[0];
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

You'll need to modify it slightly for custom post types... just add `AND wp_posts.post_type = 'my_cpt'` somewhere in there.

Comment: I needed to slightly tweak it. I think prepare() requires you to give at least one format argument %s ( see https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/270970/11914. But worked and upvoted.

Comment: What makes this the *real* solution?

Comment: @idleberg Because at the time I posted my answer, the other person who answered misread the question. They gave an example of how to get all posts sorted by the year, but the OP wanted to get a list of years that have posts.

Comment: This does work, however, it retrieves all posts disregarding the type -- make sure to apply appropriate post type filter (WHERE post_type = 'posts') else it will also return page posts too.

Comment: I get a 'The query argument of wpdb::prepare() must have a placeholder' notice with this code with debug mode turned on. Please edit this answer to include placeholders.

Comment: @user45288 Why not just remove the prepare then if there are no parameters?

Answer (score 3):

You could use this function to get all the post years in a array, which you could use to loop with.

```
$terms_year = array(
    'post_type'         => array('YOUR_CPT'),
);

$years = array();
$query_year = new WP_Query( $terms_year );

if ( $query_year->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $query_year->have_posts() ) : $query_year->the_post();
        $year = get_the_date('Y');
        if(!in_array($year, $years)){
            $years[] = $year;
        }
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();
endif;

// Echo the years out wherever you want

echo '<pre>';
print_r($years);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: This solution works fine when the typo is fixed (replace `$query_jaar` with `query_year`).

Answer (score 2):

You could use a WP function and a shortcode this way :

```
add_shortcode( 'archives', '_get_archived_posts' );
function _get_archived_posts( $atts ) {

 $a = shortcode_atts( array(
    'type'            => 'yearly',
    'limit'           => '',
    'format'          => '', 
    'before'          => '',
    'after'           => '',
    'show_post_count' => false,
    'echo'            => 0,
    'order'           => 'DESC'
), $atts, 'filter_archives_sc' );

    return wp_get_archives($a);
}
```

[Source](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_get_archives)

Answer (score 0):

```
// Get all years posts publish;
function get_posts_years_array($post_type = 'post') {

    global $wpdb;
    $result = array();

    $query_prepare = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT YEAR(post_date) FROM ($wpdb->posts) WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND post_type = %s GROUP BY YEAR(post_date) DESC", $post_type);

    $years = $wpdb->get_results($query_prepare);

    if ( is_array( $years ) && count( $years ) > 0 ) {
        foreach ( $years as $year ) {
            $result[] = json_decode(json_encode($year), true);
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I took the solution from @Gavin and enhanced it to add support for any post type and any post status:

```
/**
 * Get an array of available years for any post type with any post statuses
 * @see https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/273627/18713
 */
private function get_years_with_posts(
    string $post_type = 'post',
    array $post_stati = ['publish']
): array {
    /** @var wpdb $wpdb */
    global $wpdb;

    /** Convert the $post_stati array to the MySql IN equivalent */
    $post_status_in = "('" . implode("', '", array_map('esc_sql', $post_stati)) . "')";

    /** Prepare the query with the selected post type */
    $query = $wpdb->prepare(
        "SELECT YEAR(post_date)
        FROM {$wpdb->posts}
        WHERE post_status IN $post_status_in
        AND post_type = %s
        GROUP BY YEAR(post_date) DESC",
        $post_type
    );

    $years = $wpdb->get_results($query, ARRAY_N);

    return array_column($years, 0);
}
```

Usage example: Retrieve all published and future posts of the type `event`:

```
$avaliable_years = get_years_with_posts('event', ['publish', 'future']);
```